# Setting SharePoint 2013 Workflow Approval Status via Task Outcome

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval-process

Moving from SharePoint 2010 OOTB workflows to the new SharePoint 2013 workflows is proving to be a bit painful IMO.

1. On my document library I set content approval , content type management and versioning. I have  left out check in and checkout to speed up my testing
2. Create a single (KISS) stage workflow in SPD2013 associated with my Document Library
3. I upload my document set the various properties as defined in my custom content type
   Document "Approval Status" states "Draft".
4. Checkin (if required) and Publish a major version of the document, "Approval Status" is "Pending"
5. I manually trigger the my w/f setting myself as the approver
   I want  pass my Task outcome (Variable:Outcome) to the Approval Status property in my current item

   ```
   If Variable:Outcome equals Approved
     Log "User has Approved so Approve the document"
     then Update Item: Field Approval Status , Value Outcome
   ```

However, all I see is the above log message, the Approval Status reverts to "Draft" and the workflow hangs.

Comment: I think updating the current item again require approval. And hence the status changes to Draft

Comment: This is what I thought @AmalHashim, but how on earth do I Approve my document; as you do manually via he UI, without "Editing" the item in the w/F. No Workflow Action "Approve Current Item" ;-(

Comment: Have you tried "Set Content Approval Status to Approved"? http://kanithi.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/approval-workflow-does-not-update-the-approval-status-of-items/

Comment: @AmalHashim I don't think that is available on a SharePoint 2013 workflow - the blog post refers to 2010 workflow in SPD.  Good idea though. Tricky this issue.

Comment: looking at this as you gave me an idea http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77158/sharepoint-2013-content-approval-with-workflow-does-not-update-approval-state

Comment: The only thing the Action "Set Content Approval Status" is only available in spd SharePoint 2010 workflows.... You couldn't make this up!

Comment: I am no nearer to resolving this. For my demo, I build a 2010 approval workflow in SPD which works perfectly.  It seems unnecessarily more difficult to reproduce as a sp2013 workflow.